# no log4j logs created on the disk from the app (jboss eap 6.3 is used for AS)

Tags: log4j

I have issues with the log4j logs. Got the the following erroro which I can see in the server log file (JBoss EAP 6.3 is used as AS):

17:41:24,412 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) log4j:WARN No such property [reconnectiondelay] in org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender.

17:41:24,413 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) log4j:WARN No such property [remotehost] in org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender.

17:41:24,414 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [com.siemens.sfs.pegasus.be.logging.DailyRollingFileAppender].
.
.
.

in the log4j.properties the following arfe setted:

for the fileappender

> log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}: %5p [%t]
>   %c{1} (%F:%L) - %m%n
>   log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
>   log4j.appender.file.File=@@log4j.pegasus.log.file
>   log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
>   log4j.appender.file=com.siemens.sfs.pegasus.be.logging.DailyRollingFileAppender

for the socketappender

> log4j.appender.server.Remotehost=localhost
>   log4j.appender.server.Reconnectiondelay=10000
>   log4j.appender.server.Port=4560
>   log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender

Can anybody help why aren't the logs created?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the host property or environment property:

org.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false

This tells JBoss to use the server logging config and not the logging config of the application being deployed.

See Section 14.4.2 Disable Per-deployment Logging:
[JBoss EAP 6.3 Administration and Configuration Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/pdf/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-6.3-Administration_and_Configuration_Guide-en-US.pdf)